# Upper bound on the Lusternick-Schnirelman category by the dimension of the space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

We know that a lower bound on the LS category is given by the cuplength.
I am interested in knowing if there is a criteria in terms of homology or homotopy of the space (assume a compact manifold) so that the dimension of the space provides an upper bound on the category. For example this is true for simply connected spaces, follows from $Cat_{LS}(X) \leq \frac{1}{2} \big(cd(\pi_1(X)) + \dim(X)\big)$, where
$cd(\pi_1(X))$ is the cohomological dimension of $\pi_1(X)$. This also suggest that the dimension may have some role in the bound.

Comment: If $X$ is path-connected, locally contractible and paracompact then $\operatorname{cat}(X)\leq \dim(X)$, the covering dimension. In particular for an $n$-manifold the category cannot exceed $n$. (Here I'm using the noramlization in which the category of a point is zero.)

Comment: By the way, there must be some symbols missing from your upper bound, as I can't add a number and a space.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I have edited it now.

Comment: @ Michael Albanese: How do you prove the statement in your comment for manifolds? (For general spaces, it is false! E.g. look at acyclic non-contractible spaces. There also seem to be examples for bigger $k$, see the paragraph after exercise 1.6 in https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~tcutler/pdf/Week%201%20-%20LS%20Category.pdf)

Comment: @JensReinhold: Sorry, I got confused between the Lusternik-Schnirelman category and cup length. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: Mark's comment answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ is path-connected, locally contractible and paracompact then $\operatorname{cat}(X)\leq\dim(X)$, the covering dimension. This is Theorem 1.7 in the book *Lusternik-Schnirelmann Category* by Cornea, Lupton, Oprea and Tanré. (Here I'm using the normalization convention used in that book, in which the LS-category of a point is zero.) In particular the LS-category of an $n$-manifold cannot exceed $n$.

As well as the result (due to Dranishnikov) mentioned in the question, this can also be strengthened by considering the connectivity of the space: If $X$ is $r$-connected, then $\operatorname{cat}(X)\leq \dim(X)/r$. This is easily proved once you know the interpretation of LS-category in terms of the Ganea fibrations and basic obstruction theory.